# how to remove border in textfield fieldset in material ui

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I need to remove the border. I used some css from stack overflow but the issue is not fixed yet . If any one please help me to fixed this issue .I shall be very thank full.

what css I write to remove the border.

[image]

```js
<TextField
  variant="outlined"
  margin="normal"
  required
  fullWidth
  id="phoneNumber"
  disableUnderline={false}
  // label="Phone Number"
  name="phoneNumber"
  autoComplete="phoneNumber"
  autoFocus

  onChange={handlePhoneNumberChange}
  className={classes.textField}
  placeholder="Phone Number"
  InputProps={{
    startAdornment: (
      <InputAdornment position="start">
        <AccountCircle />
      </InputAdornment>
    ),
  }}
/>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.1.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.1.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`InputProps` can be passed to the style the variants of the inputs. For `outlined` input there a class named `.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline` which sets the border in this question's case. To modify this class, pass the styles to the `notchedOutline` prop in `InputProps`.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  noBorder: {
    border: "none",
  },
}));

const TextInput = props => {
  const { onChange, type} = props;
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <TextField
      variant="outlined"
      margin="normal"
      required
      fullWidth
      id="phoneNumber"
      disableUnderline={false}
      // label="Phone Number"
      name="phoneNumber"
      autoComplete="phoneNumber"
      autoFocus
      classes={{notchedOutline:classes.input}}

      // onChange={handlePhoneNumberChange}
      className={classes.textField}
      placeholder="Phone Number"
      InputProps={{
        startAdornment: (
          <InputAdornment position="start">
            <AccountCircle />
          </InputAdornment>
        ),
        classes:{notchedOutline:classes.noBorder}
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Here is the working sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-nhlde

Comment: Great answer! In my case, using TS, the `notchedOutline` class is only available in classes to `InputProps`.  Like...
```tsx
<TextField
  InputProps={{
    classes:{notchedOutline:classes.noBorder}
  }}
>
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this.. Doesn't work..
I found this.. It works very nicely..
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-rzdw0

Comment: For this to work, makeStyles has to be imported from '@mui/styles', as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69582795/mui-v5-typescript-makestyles-returns-never

Answer (score 71):

I was looking for a borderless text-field and this is working for me...

```
<TextField
  variant="standard" // <== changed this
  margin="normal"
  required
  fullWidth
  id="phoneNumber"
  name="phoneNumber"
  autoComplete="phoneNumber"
  autoFocus
  onChange={handlePhoneNumberChange}
  placeholder="Phone Number"
  InputProps={{
    startAdornment: <AccountCircle />, // <== adjusted this
    disableUnderline: true, // <== added this
  }}
/>
```

These 2 props seem to be the key...

```
variant="standard"
 InputProps={{
        disableUnderline: true,
      }}
```

Comment: and also variant="standard" as disableUnderline will have no effect without that

Answer (score 57):

to remove border in TextField fieldset in MUI 5,

simply add following.

```
    sx={{
      "& fieldset": { border: 'none' },
    }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Saved me over an hour of time.

Comment: Definitely the way to go!

Answer (score 15):

**For Outlined TextField**

If you want to remove outlines from the outlined text field. Then add this in your TextField

```
 sx={{border: 'none',"& fieldset": { border: 'none' },}}
```

Here is your code...

```
 <TextField
  variant="outlined"
  sx={{border: 'none', "& fieldset": { border: 'none' },}}
  margin="normal"
  required
  fullWidth
  id="phoneNumber"
  disableUnderline={false}
  // label="Phone Number"
  name="phoneNumber"
  autoComplete="phoneNumber"
  autoFocus
  onChange={handlePhoneNumberChange}
  className={classes.textField}
  placeholder="Phone Number"
  InputProps={{
    startAdornment: (
      <InputAdornment position="start">
        <AccountCircle />
      </InputAdornment>
    ),
  }}
/>
```

**For Standard TextField**

If you want to remove underline from the standard text field. Then add this in your TextField

```
InputProps={{ disableUnderline: true }}
```

Here is code

```
<TextField
 fullWidth
 placeholder="Search..."
 InputProps={{ disableUnderline: true }}
/>
```

Answer (score 9):

I found this [InputBase](https://material-ui.com/api/input-base/#inputbase-api)
It works very nicely.
This is exactly what you should use.

They have provided the sandbox too
[Sandbox InputBase](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-rzdw0)

To remove border you can simply use

```
<InputBase placeholder="Hello.." />
```

Answer (score 5):

In your textField style add `outline: 'none'`

Comment: Try changing variant prop of your text field to `variant='standard'`

Comment: If you don't want the underline and a true naked input you could also `import InputBase from "@material-ui/core/InputBase";` and replace the `<TextField />` component with the `<InputBase />` component. I tried this and verified it works.

Comment: input icons will be no more there on using `<InputBase/>`.

Answer (score 5):

As at 2022, if your using MUI >= version 5, you can use some solutions here, and currently there's no where in the doc on how do this in Textfield.

Another nice component MUI provides is the Input, and luckily for us it accepts almost all props passed to Textfield, that's where you can do   disableUnderline={false} and it will work as expected.

```
    <Input
      disableUnderline={true}
      variant="standard"
      autoFocus
      onChange={yourChangeHandler}
      value={value}
      placeholder="Title"
      fullWidth
    />
```

Answer (score 4):

Finally, the following css works (2022)

```
  '& .MuiInput-root': {
    '&:before, :after, :hover:not(.Mui-disabled):before': {
      borderBottom: 0,
    },
  },
```

Comment: it only works when variant="standard"

Answer (score 2):

Added  **sx prop with below attributes in TextField** and it worked fine for me

```
 <TextField
      sx={{
        input: {
          border: "none",
        },
        "::placeholder": { color: "white" },
      }}
 
    />
```

Comment: this is simplest, and work like charm, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The documentation doesn't offer any good way to do this
So you can select the `Mui` selector for that element and modify it directly
This worked for me.
You can override the css

```
<TextField
  id="outlined-basic"
  label="Outlined"
  variant="outlined"
  sx={{ "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": { border: "none" } }}
 />
     
<TextField
   id="filled-basic"
   label="Filled"
   variant="filled"
   sx={{
          "& .MuiFilledInput-underline:before": {
            borderBottom: "none",
          },
          "& .MuiFilledInput-underline:after": {
            borderBottom: "none",
          },
          "& .MuiFilledInput-underline:hover:not(.Mui-disabled):before": {
            borderBottom: "none",
          },
        }}
 />
```

Please check it in   [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-shadow-515yoi?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```
".MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": { border: "none" },
```

to the sx prop.

This works both for MUI Select and Textfield

Answer (score 1):

disableUnderline
If true, the input will not have an underline.

```
<Input
            variant="standard"
            disableUnderline={true}
            required
            color="info"
            fullWidth
            margin="dense"
            focused
          />
```

[API](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/input/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the border for all MuiOutlinedInput components, add this to your theme's `components` object:

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  // ...
  components: {
    // ...
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
      styleOverrides: {
        notchedOutline: {
          border: 'none',
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```