# Material UI Autocomplete not working using modified TextField

Tags: reactjs, search, autocomplete, material-ui, textfield

I need to modify the Autocomplete Highlight provided as an example to fit my needs. (https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#autocomplete)

The Highlight example provided has borders so I used the solution from this link ([how to remove border in textfield fieldset in material ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65161428/how-to-remove-border-in-textfield-fieldset-in-material-ui)) to modify my TextField and remove it's border and it works except that when I type in the search input I don't get the autocomplete suggestions.

I also replaced the Icon, and ended up with the following code:

```
/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import parse from 'autosuggest-highlight/parse';
import match from 'autosuggest-highlight/match';
import { InputAdornment, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  noBorder: {
    border: "none",
  },
}));

export default function Highlights() {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="highlights-demo"
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            // disableUnderline={false}
            autoFocus
            classes={{notchedOutline:classes.input}}

            // onChange={handlePhoneNumberChange}
            className={classes.textField}
            placeholder="Search..."
            InputProps={{
              startAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                  <SearchIcon />
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
              classes:{notchedOutline:classes.noBorder}
            }}
          />
        // <TextField {...params} label="Highlights" variant="outlined" margin="normal" />
      )}
      renderOption={(option, { inputValue }) => {
        const matches = match(option.title, inputValue);
        const parts = parse(option.title, matches);

        return (
          <div>
            {parts.map((part, index) => (
              <span key={index} style={{ fontWeight: part.highlight ? 700 : 400 }}>
                {part.text}
              </span>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
  { title: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974 },
  { title: 'The Dark Knight', year: 2008 },
  { title: '12 Angry Men', year: 1957 },
  { title: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { title: 'Pulp Fiction', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King', year: 2003 },
  { title: 'The Good, the Bad and the Ugly', year: 1966 },
  { title: 'Fight Club', year: 1999 },
  { title: 'The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring', year: 2001 },
  { title: 'Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back', year: 1980 },
  { title: 'Forrest Gump', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'Inception', year: 2010 },
  { title: 'The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers', year: 2002 },
  { title: "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest", year: 1975 },
  { title: 'Goodfellas', year: 1990 },
  { title: 'The Matrix', year: 1999 },
  { title: 'Seven Samurai', year: 1954 },
  { title: 'Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope', year: 1977 },
  { title: 'City of God', year: 2002 },
  { title: 'Se7en', year: 1995 },
  { title: 'The Silence of the Lambs', year: 1991 },
  { title: "It's a Wonderful Life", year: 1946 },
  { title: 'Life Is Beautiful', year: 1997 },
  { title: 'The Usual Suspects', year: 1995 },
  { title: 'Léon: The Professional', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'Spirited Away', year: 2001 },
  { title: 'Saving Private Ryan', year: 1998 },
  { title: 'Once Upon a Time in the West', year: 1968 },
  { title: 'American History X', year: 1998 },
  { title: 'Interstellar', year: 2014 },
  { title: 'Casablanca', year: 1942 },
  { title: 'City Lights', year: 1931 },
  { title: 'Psycho', year: 1960 },
  { title: 'The Green Mile', year: 1999 },
  { title: 'The Intouchables', year: 2011 },
  { title: 'Modern Times', year: 1936 },
  { title: 'Raiders of the Lost Ark', year: 1981 },
  { title: 'Rear Window', year: 1954 },
  { title: 'The Pianist', year: 2002 },
  { title: 'The Departed', year: 2006 },
  { title: 'Terminator 2: Judgment Day', year: 1991 },
  { title: 'Back to the Future', year: 1985 },
  { title: 'Whiplash', year: 2014 },
  { title: 'Gladiator', year: 2000 },
  { title: 'Memento', year: 2000 },
  { title: 'The Prestige', year: 2006 },
  { title: 'The Lion King', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'Apocalypse Now', year: 1979 },
  { title: 'Alien', year: 1979 },
  { title: 'Sunset Boulevard', year: 1950 },
  { title: 'Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb', year: 1964 },
  { title: 'The Great Dictator', year: 1940 },
  { title: 'Cinema Paradiso', year: 1988 },
  { title: 'The Lives of Others', year: 2006 },
  { title: 'Grave of the Fireflies', year: 1988 },
  { title: 'Paths of Glory', year: 1957 },
  { title: 'Django Unchained', year: 2012 },
  { title: 'The Shining', year: 1980 },
  { title: 'WALL·E', year: 2008 },
  { title: 'American Beauty', year: 1999 },
  { title: 'The Dark Knight Rises', year: 2012 },
  { title: 'Princess Mononoke', year: 1997 },
  { title: 'Aliens', year: 1986 },
  { title: 'Oldboy', year: 2003 },
  { title: 'Once Upon a Time in America', year: 1984 },
  { title: 'Witness for the Prosecution', year: 1957 },
  { title: 'Das Boot', year: 1981 },
  { title: 'Citizen Kane', year: 1941 },
  { title: 'North by Northwest', year: 1959 },
  { title: 'Vertigo', year: 1958 },
  { title: 'Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi', year: 1983 },
  { title: 'Reservoir Dogs', year: 1992 },
  { title: 'Braveheart', year: 1995 },
  { title: 'M', year: 1931 },
  { title: 'Requiem for a Dream', year: 2000 },
  { title: 'Amélie', year: 2001 },
  { title: 'A Clockwork Orange', year: 1971 },
  { title: 'Like Stars on Earth', year: 2007 },
  { title: 'Taxi Driver', year: 1976 },
  { title: 'Lawrence of Arabia', year: 1962 },
  { title: 'Double Indemnity', year: 1944 },
  { title: 'Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind', year: 2004 },
  { title: 'Amadeus', year: 1984 },
  { title: 'To Kill a Mockingbird', year: 1962 },
  { title: 'Toy Story 3', year: 2010 },
  { title: 'Logan', year: 2017 },
  { title: 'Full Metal Jacket', year: 1987 },
  { title: 'Dangal', year: 2016 },
  { title: 'The Sting', year: 1973 },
  { title: '2001: A Space Odyssey', year: 1968 },
  { title: "Singin' in the Rain", year: 1952 },
  { title: 'Toy Story', year: 1995 },
  { title: 'Bicycle Thieves', year: 1948 },
  { title: 'The Kid', year: 1921 },
  { title: 'Inglourious Basterds', year: 2009 },
  { title: 'Snatch', year: 2000 },
  { title: '3 Idiots', year: 2009 },
  { title: 'Monty Python and the Holy Grail', year: 1975 },
];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for autocomplete to work , you also need to pass on the `InputProps` down to custom textfield.
So I would change your `renderInput` function like this:

```
 renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            // disableUnderline={false}
            autoFocus
            classes={{notchedOutline:classes.input}}

            // onChange={handlePhoneNumberChange}
            className={classes.textField}
            placeholder="Search..."
            InputProps={{
             ...params.InputProps, // this is new
              startAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                  <SearchIcon />
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
              classes:{notchedOutline:classes.noBorder}
            }}
          />
        // <TextField {...params} label="Highlights" variant="outlined" margin="normal" />
      )}
```

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-playground-forked-3o8o4?file=/app.jsx)