# MUI v5 Typescript makeStyles returns never

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, jss

I'm trying to migrate my components from MUI v4 to v5, and I've gotten to a point where I don't know how to migrate my `makeStyles` components.

Before, I had something like this that was working:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    someMore: 'styles'
  }
}));
// ...

const Component: FC = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const classes = useStyles(theme);

   return (
      <Paper elevation={3} className={classes.paper}>
         <Stuff />
      </Paper>
   )
}
```

Now I'm getting an error on the `useStyles` call:

> This expression is not callable.
> Type 'never' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

What is the workaround in this case?

Comment: Can you fork [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/basictextfields-material-demo-forked-5q393?file=/demo.tsx) codesandbox and recreate the error?

Comment: I already see some differences. I'm importing `makeStyles` and `useTheme` from `@mui/material`. I'm also seeing a `StyledEngineProvider` at root. I'm using `ThemeProvider`. Is there a difference? Which should I use?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot use [`makeStyles`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui) from `@mui/material` (you'll get an error if you do so) because it's been moved to `@mui/styles` as `makeStyles` is marked as deprecated.  That's why the type is `never`; it's not there! The function is empty and its [only purpose](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-material/src/styles/makeStyles.js) is to tell you where `makeStyles` is located now.

`@mui/styles` is a legacy package and it's not recommended for use in v5. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69508854/9449426) answer to know more about the differences between the two of them. For alternatives, you can use [`styled`/`sx` prop](https://mui.com/system/basics/#why-use-the-system).

Comment: I will look into it on Monday!

Comment: Thanks for the insights! If the `@mui/styles` is legacy now, what package should I use?

Comment: @Vivere MUI v5 uses `@mui/system` and have 2 new APIs `styled`/`sx` for that. See [this](https://mui.com/system/basics/#why-use-the-system)