# MUI can't read palette value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use typescript with MUI in reactJS ,but it keep giving me this error , I have tried to uninstall MUI packages and then install it again but nothing changes, it don't give me any error in typescript so it hard to tell why this error happen

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'primary')
```

I have this setup for MUI

My theme configuration

```
export type Mode = "dark" | "light";

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
   interface Palette {
    general:{
      purple: string,
      grayLight: string,
      linear: string,
      white: string
    }
  }

  interface PaletteOptions {
    general?:{
      purple: string,
      grayLight: string,
      linear: string,
      white: string
    }
  }
}

export const themeConfig = (mode: Mode) => {
  return {
    palette: {
      mode: mode,
      primary: {
        main: primMain,
        dark: primDark,
        light: primLight,
      },
      secondary: {
        main: secMain,
        dark: secDark,
        light: secLight,
      },
      error: {
        main: errorMain,
        dark: errorDark,
      },
      success: {
        main: successMain,
        dark: sucessDark,
      },
      text: {
        primary: textPrimary,
        secondary: textSecondary,
      },
      general: {
        purple: commonPurple,
        grayLight: commonGrayLight,
        linear: comminLinear,
        white: commonWhite
      },
    },
  };
};
```

Create theme init

```
import { createTheme} from '@mui/material/styles';
import {themeConfig} from '../styles/styleTheme'

const theme = createTheme(themeConfig('dark'))
```

Use makeStyles method

```
import {makeStyles,createStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import { Theme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme:Theme) => ({
    root: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark,
    },
  }),
);
```

Used in component
so when I use this ('text.secondary') it work fine but when I use this (classes.root) it throw me the error I mentioned above

```
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import { ThemeProvider} from '@mui/material/styles';
   const classes = useStyles();
 <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Button  className={classes.root} sx={{color:'text.secondary'}}>style</Button>
 </ThemeProvider>
```

My react component

```
import React from 'react'
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next'
import { ThemeProvider} from '@mui/material/styles';
import {makeStyles,createStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import theme from './config/createTheme';
import {handleLangChange} from './services/changeLang'
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import { Theme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme:Theme) => ({
    root: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark,
    },
  }),
);



function App() {
  const {t} = useTranslation()
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Button  className={classes.root} sx={{color:'text.secondary'}}>style</Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: 1. Did you pass the `theme` to `ThemeProvider`? 2. Where did you import `ThemeProvider`?

Comment: yes I did ,I have updated the question with these details @NearHuscarl

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `useStyles` to create a stylesheet and reference the `theme` object in the root component where you also return the `ThemeProvider` to pass the `theme` down, so the theme is not available there. To fix it, move your `useStyles` call to a child component where it can access the `theme` from the parent:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Content />
</ThemeProvider>
```

```
const Content = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Button className={classes.root} sx={{ color: 'text.secondary' }}>
      style
    </Button>
  );
};
```

Also note that [it's not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69586291/9449426) to use `useStyles`/`withStyles` in v5 because they're deprecated APIs.

**EDIT:** You can see [system section](https://mui.com/system/basics/#main-content) for more detail. This is how it'd look in v5:

```
import MuiButton from '@mui/material/Button';

const Button = styled(MuiButton)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: theme.palette.secondary.main,
}));
```

`sx` prop:

```
<Button sx={{ color: 'secondary.main' }}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Mind if you explain how the code should look in v5, if it's not too complicated?

Comment: You can see [system section](https://mui.com/system/basics/#main-content) for more detail. Unless you have a specific problem about the new API. I also updated the answer for you. @SilviuBurcea

Comment: U da real MVP :)