# How to properly use Styled() with MUI V5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am having an issue trying to use MUI Styled () on bigger scale: can someone take a look at the code we used to use in prior versions and let me know how to replicate it in MUI V5.

Old way:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "#fdfdff",
  },
  pageHeader: {
    padding: theme.spacing(4),
    display: "flex",
    marginBottom: theme.spacing,
  },
  pageIcon: {
    display: "inline-block",
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    color: "#3c44b1",
  },
  pageTitle: {
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing(4),
    "& .MuiTypography-subtitle2": {
      opacity: "0.6",
    },
  },
}));
export default function PageHeader(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { title, subTitle, icon } = props;
  return (
    <Paper elevation={0} square className={classes.root}>
      <div className={classes.pageHeader}>
        <Card className={classes.pageIcon}>{icon}</Card>
        <div className={classes.pageTitle}>
          <Typography variant="h6" component="div">
            {title}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="subtitle2" component="div">
            {subTitle}
          </Typography>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit v4 example]

My attempt to accomplish the same in MUI V5 is not working properly. it renders but it doesn't look the same and it's all over the place.

```
const rootStyle = styled("div")({
  backgroundColor: "#fdfdff",
});
const headerStyle = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  padding: theme.spacing(4),
  display: "flex",
  marginBottom: theme.spacing,
}));
const iconStyle = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  display: "inline-block",
  padding: theme.spacing(2),
  color: "#3c44b1",
}));
const titleStyle = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  paddingLeft: theme.spacing(4),
  "& .MuiTypography-subtitle2": {
    opacity: "0.6",
  },
}));

export default function PageHeader(props) {
  const { title, subTitle, icon } = props;
  return (
    <rootStyle>
      <Paper elevation={0} square>
        <headerStyle>
          <iconStyle>
            <Card>{icon}</Card>
          </iconStyle>
          <titleStyle>
            <Typography variant="h6" component="div">
              {title}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="subtitle2" component="div">
              {subTitle}
            </Typography>
          </titleStyle>
        </headerStyle>
      </Paper>
    </rootStyle>
  );
}
```

I am new to MUI and there are not a lot of examples out there that cover this. I truly appreciate your help!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69723309/9449426) should solve your problem.

Comment: Here the docs for the new way of spacing: https://mui.com/system/spacing/

Comment: I think the part in App.js is correct, the question now how can we replace makeStyles with the new way. I am not just after spacing; I am after how to use theme in v5

Comment: @Moe you can use `sx` prop/`styled` in v5. There is a bunch of examples on the docs to show you how to use them.

Comment: I updated the question; can you provide an example of how to replicate what I have using styled

Comment: @NearHuscarl can you a look at my updated question and let me know your thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below is a v5 version of your code with the same look as the v4 version. I added default values for the props just for demonstration purposes.

You had two main issues:

1. You added additional div layers for the styling rather than styling the elements that originally received the styles (e.g. `Paper`, `Card`).
2. You assigned the `styled` divs to variable names that start with a lowercase letter which caused them to be rendered as DOM tags rather than components (so the styling would have been completely ignored).

From https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component:

> React treats components starting with lowercase letters as DOM tags.

```
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import PersonIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Person";

const StyledPaper = styled(Paper)({
  backgroundColor: "#fdfdff"
});
const HeaderDiv = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  padding: theme.spacing(4),
  display: "flex",
  marginBottom: theme.spacing
}));
const StyledCard = styled(Card)(({ theme }) => ({
  display: "inline-block",
  padding: theme.spacing(2),
  color: "#3c44b1"
}));
const TitleDiv = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  paddingLeft: theme.spacing(4),
  "& .MuiTypography-subtitle2": {
    opacity: "0.6"
  }
}));

export default function PageHeader(props) {
  const {
    title = "Title",
    subTitle = "sub-title",
    icon = <PersonIcon />
  } = props;
  return (
    <StyledPaper elevation={0} square>
      <HeaderDiv>
        <StyledCard>{icon}</StyledCard>
        <TitleDiv>
          <Typography variant="h6" component="div">
            {title}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="subtitle2" component="div">
            {subTitle}
          </Typography>
        </TitleDiv>
      </HeaderDiv>
    </StyledPaper>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit v5 example]

An alternative (and much more concise) way to convert the v4 code to v5 is to use the `sx` prop:

```
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import PersonIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Person";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

export default function PageHeader(props) {
  const {
    title = "Title",
    subTitle = "sub-title",
    icon = <PersonIcon />
  } = props;
  return (
    <Paper elevation={0} square sx={{ bgcolor: "#fdfdff" }}>
      <Box sx={{ p: 4, display: "flex", mb: 1 }}>
        <Card sx={{ display: "inline-block", p: 2, color: "#3c44b1" }}>
          {icon}
        </Card>
        <Box sx={{ pl: 4, "& .MuiTypography-subtitle2": { opacity: 0.6 } }}>
          <Typography variant="h6" component="div">
            {title}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="subtitle2" component="div">
            {subTitle}
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit v5 example using sx]

Here is one more option using a single `styled` call, though in my opinion this would be more brittle to maintain than the other options:

```
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import PersonIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Person";

const StyledPaper = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: "#fdfdff",
  "& > div": {
    padding: theme.spacing(4),
    display: "flex",
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(1),
    "& .MuiCard-root": {
      display: "inline-block",
      padding: theme.spacing(2),
      color: "#3c44b1"
    },
    "& > div": {
      paddingLeft: theme.spacing(4),
      "& .MuiTypography-subtitle2": {
        opacity: "0.6"
      }
    }
  }
}));

export default function PageHeader(props) {
  const {
    title = "Title",
    subTitle = "sub-title",
    icon = <PersonIcon />
  } = props;
  return (
    <StyledPaper elevation={0} square>
      <div>
        <Card>{icon}</Card>
        <div>
          <Typography variant="h6" component="div">
            {title}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="subtitle2" component="div">
            {subTitle}
          </Typography>
        </div>
      </div>
    </StyledPaper>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit v5 example with one styled call]

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation: another question if I may, is there a way to consolidate Styled components simliary as we did before with useStyles (old way). passing the theme in each const component is repetitive. is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: @Moe There isn't a straightforward way to avoid passing the theme for each `styled` call unless you do all the styling via a single `styled` call and then target the descendant elements in the styles, but I think that would result in more complicated styles that are a little more difficult to maintain. One alternative is to use the `sx` prop instead of `styled` -- I've added an example of that.

Comment: Thank you so much again! I tried the single style and I wasn't able to call the component. so I asked to know the right and best way of doing it. So to summarize,  either break them into  to small components or use sx to style.

Comment: @Moe I've added an additional example showing one way of doing it with a single `styled` call. There isn't really one "right and best way" to style things -- there are many options with different trade-offs depending on the specifics of your scenario.

Comment: Thanks so much, I think the community will appreciate your answers as well. I truly appreciate you taking the time to help us with this.

Comment: hello @Ryan, can you take a look at this post and let me know your thoughts. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70140504/how-to-pass-a-custom-style-to-mui-v5-styled-component/70141256?noredirect=1#comment123989959_70141256