# How to pass a custom style to MUI V5 styled component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

Using MUI V5, how can I pass a custom style to a button component? Here is what I have been trying to merge the old way with the new MUI v5 but it's not working.

```
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import React from "react";

const StyledButton = styled(Button)(({ theme }) => ({
  root: {
    minWidth: 0,
    margin: theme.spacing(0.5),
  },
  secondary: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.light,
    "& .MuiButton-label": {
      color: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
  },
  primary: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.light,
    "& .MuiButton-label": {
      color: theme.palette.primary.main,
    },
  },
}));

export default function ActionButton(props) {
  const { color, children, onClick } = props;

  return (
    <Button
      className={`${StyledButton["root"]} ${StyledButton[color]}`}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      {children}
    </Button>
  );
}
```

Now I would like to call this Button and give it color="secondary"

```
import ActionButton from "./ActionButton";
import { Close } from "@mui/icons-material";
export default function Header() {
    return (
       <ActionButton color="secondary">
            <Close />
       </ActionButton>  
     
   )
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your code was an attempt to migrate from code using `makeStyles/useStyles`, but `styled` works quite a bit differently. You can't use it to generate multiple CSS classes like `makeStyles` does (`StyledButton["root"]` and `StyledButton[color]` will be `undefined`). `styled` will generate a single CSS class that is then passed in the `className` prop to the wrapped component (e.g. `Button`). Instead of trying to create multiple CSS classes with logic to decide which class to apply, with `styled` you can leverage props (e.g. the `color` prop) to generate dynamic styles within the single CSS class that is generated.

Below is an example that I think achieves the effect your code was aiming for. My example doesn't do anything with `MuiButton-label` because that class doesn't exist in v5 (and the `<span>` that the class was applied to inside the `<button` in v4 also does not exist), and I believe the [default Button styles](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v5.2.1/packages/mui-material/src/Button/Button.js#L166) set `color` as desired when the `color` prop is allowed to passed through to `Button`.

```
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const StyledButton = styled(Button)(({ theme, color }) => ({
  minWidth: 0,
  margin: theme.spacing(0.5),
  backgroundColor: color ? theme.palette[color].light : undefined
}));

export default StyledButton;
```

[image: Edit styled button]

Comment: Perfect, again thanks for backing your answer with detailed explanation. I greatly appreciate it; so much cleaner.