# How to style Toolbar with Material UI v5 with 'styled' instead of 'makeStyles' with this class instance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, create-react-app

I'm a newbie to JS, ReactJS, and Material UI. I was following a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/nEQhafa37-c?t=646) on building a simple ReactJS webpage, but looks like the person was using Material UI v4 and now that Material UI v5 is out, a few of the APIs and tools used in the tut are outdated (withStyles, makeStyles). Around 10:46 in the video, he is showing how he is creating classes to stylize each part of the Toolbar.

I'm trying to figure out how I could accomplish the same stylizing for the Toolbar and its Typography components using that same exact structure, via injecting it with className?

My Code:

**Navbar.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import logo from '../assets/logo.svg'               // imported assets for the navbar
import logoMobile from '../assets/logoMobile.svg'
import { Toolbar, Typography } from '@mui/material' // these two needed for toolbar
import { styled } from '@mui/material'
import CustomButton from './CustomButton'

const styles = styled({
    bar:{       // class name
      paddingTop: "1.15rem",
      backgroundColor: "#fff",
      ['@media (max-width:780px)']:{flexMedia: "column"}, // media queries - for different devices and web-browser sizes
    },
    // logo: {
    //   width: "15%", 
    //   ['@media (max-width:780px)']: {display: "none"},
    // },
    // logoMobile:{
    //   width: "100%", 
    //   display: "none", 
    //   ['@media (max-width:780px)']: {display: "inline-block"},
    // },
    menuItem: {
      cursor: "pointer", 
      flexGrow: 1,
      "&:hover": {color:  "#4f25c8"},
      ['@media (max-width:780px)']: {paddingBottom: "1rem"},
    }

})

function NavBar() {
  const classes = styles()
  return (
    <Toolbar position="sticky" color="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)" className={classes.bar}>
      {/* <img src={logo} className={classes.logo}/>
      <img src={logoMobile} className={classes.logoMobile}/> */}
      <Typography variant="h5" className={classes.menuItem}>
        About Me
      </Typography>
      <Typography variant="h5" className={classes.menuItem}>
        Projects
      </Typography>
      <Typography variant="h5" className={classes.menuItem}>
        Resume
      </Typography>
      <Typography variant="h5" className={classes.menuItem}>
        Contact Me
      </Typography>
      <CustomButton txt="a test button!"></CustomButton>
    </Toolbar>   
  )
}

export default NavBar
```

And here's what it ends up looking like

[image]

vs what it should look like

[image]

I tried utilizing `{styled } from '@mui/material'` but I can only get the toolbar to show. But it will not apply the styling expected, from the video -- confused as to why? Also [this question accomplishes the same task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69860893/how-to-properly-use-styled-with-mui-v5), but it doesn't do it the way that I'm asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `styled` create custom components with additional styles, it attaches the styles without specifying and adding class names manually.

Here is a quick example for a `styled` version of your code: (live demo on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eyxyyg?file=src/App.js))

First use `styled` to create some custom components, in this case based on the MUI components `Toolbar` and `Typography`, with some styles attached to them.

```
//  This component based on Toolbar
const MyToolbar = styled(Toolbar)(({ theme }) => ({
  paddingTop: '1.15rem',
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)',
  position: 'sticky',
  //  Optional: consider to use theme.breakpoints for this
  ['@media (max-width:780px)']: { flexDirection: 'column' },
}));

//  This component based on Typography
const MyItem = styled(Typography)(({ theme }) => ({
  cursor: 'pointer',
  flexGrow: 1,
  '&:hover': { color: '#4f25c8' },
  //  Optional: consider to use theme.breakpoints for this
  ['@media (max-width:780px)']: { paddingBottom: '1rem' },
}));
```

While the media queries works in here, perhaps consider to use the [breakpoints](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/breakpoints/) syntax with `theme` for a potentially cleaner solution.

```
//  Optional: replaces @media line in MyToolbar
[theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: { flexDirection: 'column' }

//  Optional: replaces @media line in MyItem
[theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: { paddingBottom: '1rem' }
```

Otherwise, if it is in some (less common) situations that `theme` is not needed, then `{theme}` could be omitted in `styled` syntax, for example:

```
//  Only when theme is not needed
const MyToolbar = styled(Toolbar)({
  paddingTop: '1.15rem',
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)',
  position: 'sticky',
  ['@media (max-width:780px)']: { flexDirection: 'column' },
});

//  Only when theme is not needed
const MyItem = styled(Typography)({
  cursor: 'pointer',
  flexGrow: 1,
  '&:hover': { color: '#4f25c8' },
  ['@media (max-width:780px)']: { paddingBottom: '1rem' },
});
```

After attached with styles, the components `MyToolbar` and `MyItem` can then be used in the output, for example:

```
<MyToolbar>
  <MyItem variant="h5">About Me</MyItem>
  <MyItem variant="h5">Projects</MyItem>
  <MyItem variant="h5">Resume</MyItem>
  <MyItem variant="h5">Contact Me</MyItem>
  <Button>Custom Btn</Button>
</MyToolbar>
```

Note that the inline styles `position="sticky" color="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)"` does not work here, and is moved to the above `styled`. If inline styles are needed, consider use the [`sx` prop](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-box/#the-sx-prop).

Hope this will help.

Comment: Never responded to this, but yes this was the answer I was looking for -- thank you very much John!